# Flutter add a card widget on another screen on button tap

Tags: flutter, dart, stateful

I am working on an app in which I want to add some card widgets on the home screen when a user selects the cards on the explore screen. Since I am new to flutter I need some assistance with code.

It is like it would be adding a favourite or bookmark feature.
If you want to check the full code here is the link to the github : https://github.com/Ankitkj1999/study_lpu/tree/mark_feature
***explore.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExploreScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExploreScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListViewHome();
  }
}

class ListViewHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final titles = ["List 1", "List 2", "List 3", "List 4"];
  final subtitles = [
    "Here is list 1 subtitle",
    "Here is list 2 subtitle",
    "Here is list 3 subtitle",
    "Here is list 4 subtitle"
  ];
  // final icons = [
  //   // IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
  //   // Icons.access_alarm,
  //   // Icons.access_time,
  //   Icons.add
  // ];

  ListViewHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: titles.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(titles[index]),
              subtitle: Text(subtitles[index]),
              leading: const CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547721064-da6cfb341d50")),
              trailing: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

class pushAdd extends StatelessWidget {
  const pushAdd({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    showWidget() {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Home'),
        ),
      );
    }

    return showWidget();
  }
}
```

***home.dart***

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:study_lpu/explore.dart';
import 'package:study_lpu/fav.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'explore.dart';

// bottom navigation tutorial https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-a-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter/
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late String uid;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static const List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
    // Scaffold(
    //   body: Center(
    //     child: Text('Hot'),
    //   ),
    // ),
    pushAdd(),
    ExploreScreen(),
    RandWords(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Home'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
              onPressed: () async {
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()),
                    (route) => false);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.book_outlined),
              label: 'Explore',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_outlined),
              label: 'Profile',
            )
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
        body:
            // Center(
            //   // child: Text(uid),
            //   child: _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
            // ),
            IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: _pages,
        ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that in a basic way without using any provider. Firstly you need to put your data in a model to access the variable properly. second, in home page I defined a list of model that is empty and also defined a function that adds card to the list executed in explore page. Also you need to make a view in home page to show added card to the list

```
class MyCardModel {
  String? title;
  String? subTitle;
  String? leadingImage;

  MyCardModel(String title, String subTitle, String leadingImage) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subTitle = subTitle;
    this.leadingImage = leadingImage;
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late String uid;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<MyCardModel> listOfCard = [];

  void addCardToListMethod(MyCardModel card) {
    setState(() {
      listOfCard.add(card);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
      Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listOfCard.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(listOfCard[index].title!),
                      subtitle: Text(listOfCard[index].subTitle!),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage:
                              NetworkImage(listOfCard[index].leadingImage!)),
                    ),
                  );
                })),
      ),
      pushAdd(),
      ExploreScreen(addCardToListMethod: addCardToListMethod),
      RandWords(),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Home'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
              onPressed: () async {
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()),
                    (route) => false);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.book_outlined),
              label: 'Explore',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_outlined),
              label: 'Profile',
            )
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
        body:
            // Center(
            //   // child: Text(uid),
            //   child: _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
            // ),
            IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: _pages,
        ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}

class ExploreScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Function? addCardToListMethod;
  ExploreScreen({Key? key, this.addCardToListMethod}) : super(key: key);

  List<MyCardModel> myCardList = [
    MyCardModel("List1", "here is list 1 subtitle",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547721064-da6cfb341d50"),
    MyCardModel("List1", "here is list 1 subtitle",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547721064-da6cfb341d50")
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: myCardList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(myCardList[index].title!),
              subtitle: Text(myCardList[index].subTitle!),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage(myCardList[index].leadingImage!)),
              trailing: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  addCardToListMethod!(myCardList[index]);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: bro thank you very much for the solution. But I am struggling to solve the errors can you please see to it. you can get the full code in the github link above.

Comment: or you can point out any working example similar to this!

Comment: I saw that your explore screen is stateless then in order to access the addCardToListMethod, you do not need to write "widget" keywork in front of the method you called, I have edited my post @AnkitKumar

Comment: Do you get any other errors, if so where do you get and what the errors say

Comment: home.dart  | line 14 | Non-nullable instance field 'subTitle' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'. | line 45 | A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'Function' in a const constructor.
Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'.

Comment: explore.dart | line 3 | This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: ExploreScreen.addCardToListMethod | line 5 | Can't define a const constructor for a class with non-final fields.
Try making all of the fields final, or removing the keyword 'const' from the constructor. | line 16 | The name 'MyCardModel' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. |  17 & 21  | The method 'MyCardModel' isn't defined for the type 'ListViewHome'. |  44 | Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.

Comment: https://github.com/Ankitkj1999/study_lpu/tree/mark_feature

Comment: @AnkitKumar  your project support nullable feature which is added by flutter team by flutter 2.0. That's why you need to specify that your variable that you defined should not be null or nullable. I have edited my post again. It should work right now.